# How do I format a Currency for a Locale in Java

Tags: java, internationalization

I'm surprised that I'm having real trouble finding how to do this. It seems to me it should be pretty straightforward. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
double amount = 123.45D; //yes, I know that I should be using longs
Locale uk = Locale.UK;
Locale fr = Locale.FR;
Currency euro = Currency.getInstance("EUR");
```

How do I get instances of NumberFormat that let me print out the 123.45 value correctly formatted for the Locale? ie I want the following for the UK and France respectively :

```
€123.45
123,45 €
```

I can't use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale)` as that will format the UK format as Sterling (£). What I am looking for is `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale, Currency)`, but that doesn't seem to exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`NumberFormat.setCurrency()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setCurrency%28java.util.Currency%29) to modify the currency used for a specific `NumberFormat` acquired via `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale)`.